# Ansible separating hosts, group_vars and host_vars

Tags: ansible, yaml, ansible-inventory

I need to change some files in YAML format from one "big" yml to several smaller files. Unfortunately, I do not know which part belongs where. For example, I have the following .yml:

```
all:
  hosts:
    station01:
      dns_name: localhost
      ansible_host: localhost
    work01:
      dns_name: X.X.X.X
      ansible_host: Y.Y.Y.Y
  vars:
    yum_proxy: false
    zabbix_proxy_ip: A.A.A.A
    yum_proxy_ip:
    dns_servers:
      - B.B.B.B
      - C.C.C.C
    timezone: XXX
    ntp_servers:
      - D.D.D.D
    disable_firewall_tasks: true

  children:
    deploy:
      hosts:
        station01:
    linux:
      hosts:
        work01:
    work_users:
      hosts:
        work01:
      vars:
        users:
          - john: user
          - mike: user
```

I believe that hosts file should looke like this:

```
all:
  hosts:
    station01
    work01

  children:
    deploy:
      hosts:
        station01:
    linux:
      hosts:
        work01:
    work_users:
      hosts:
        work01:
```

The group_vars "all.yml" looks like this, I guess:

```
---
all:
  yum_proxy: false
  zabbix_proxy_ip: A.A.A.A
  yum_proxy_ip:
  dns_servers:
    - B.B.B.B
    - C.C.C.C
  timezone: XXX
  ntp_servers:
    - D.D.D.D
  disable_firewall_tasks: true
```

And this is where the problem begins. I do not know where to put the "users:". Should it be in host_vars "work01.yml" assigned to one host, like this:

```
---
work01:
  dns_name: X.X.X.X
  ansible_host: Y.Y.Y.Y
  users:
    - john: user
    - mike: user
```

Or should it be contained in the group_vars file named "work_users.yml"?

```
---
users:
  - john: user
  - mike: user
```

What the files host_vars and group_vars should look like? Any kind of help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Q: **"*What the files host_vars and group_vars should look like?*"**

A: There are more options of how to name and organize the directories and files. See [Organizing host and group variables](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/intro_inventory.html#organizing-host-and-group-variable).

**Files named after the corresponding groups and hostnames**

Below is an example of putting the variables into the files named after the corresponding groups and hostnames

```yaml
shell> cat group_vars/all.yml
---
yum_proxy: false
zabbix_proxy_ip: A.A.A.A
yum_proxy_ip:
dns_servers:
  - B.B.B.B
  - C.C.C.C
timezone: XXX
ntp_servers:
  - D.D.D.D
disable_firewall_tasks: true
```

```yaml
shell> cat group_vars/work_users.yml
---
users:
  - john: user
  - mike: user
```

```yaml
shell> cat host_vars/work01.yml
---
dns_name: X.X.X.X
ansible_host: Y.Y.Y.Y
```

```yaml
shell> cat host_vars/station01.yml
---
dns_name: localhost
ansible_host: localhost
```

---

**Files inside the directories named after the corresponding groups and hostnames**

The next option is putting the variables into the files inside the directories named after the corresponding groups and hostnames

```yaml
shell> cat group_vars/all/network.yml
---
yum_proxy: false
zabbix_proxy_ip: A.A.A.A
yum_proxy_ip:
dns_servers:
  - B.B.B.B
  - C.C.C.C
timezone: XXX
ntp_servers:
  - D.D.D.D
disable_firewall_tasks: true
```

```yaml
shell> cat group_vars/work_users/users.yml
---
users:
  - john: user
  - mike: user
```

```yaml
shell> cat host_vars/work01/network.yml
---
dns_name: X.X.X.X
ansible_host: Y.Y.Y.Y
```

```yaml
shell> cat host_vars/station01/network.yml
---
dns_name: localhost
ansible_host: localhost
```